# Is it possible to make xml file only accessible to my site/server?

Tags: php, file, security

I want to store some customer payment plan info in a file that is easier to edit than a SQL table. Right now I am storing this in an XML file in my public dir.

Is there a way to make it only accessible to my site and or server so that users can't tamper with the values? Will it be hard to "crack" if the values are being read by server side php?

Comment: you can use `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`?

Comment: Or an SQL interface such as MySQL Workbench / Navicat

Comment: Do you mean that only PHP can open/read the file? or that people cannot link to it from another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is saved outside the directory root then it cannot be accessed by the public. As long as the path is allowed by [`openbase_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) it can still be included server side with `include`, `require`, etc.